# SpriteBatch.Begin() making my model not render correctly

Tags: xna, spritebatch

I was trying to output some debug information using DrawString when I noticed my model suddenly was being rendered like it was inside-out (like the culling had been disabled or something) and the texture maps weren't applied

I commented out the DrawString method until I only had SpriteBatch.Begin() and .End() and that was enough to cause the model rendering corruption - when I commented those calls out the model rendered correctly

What could this be a symptom of? I've stripped it down to the barest of code to isolate the problem and this is what I noticed.

Draw code below (as stripped down as possible)

```
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.LightGray);
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in TIEAdvanced.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (Effect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                if (effect is BasicEffect)
                    ((BasicEffect)effect).EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
            }
        }

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, "Camera Position: " + cameraPosition.ToString(), new Vector2(10, 10), Color.Blue);
        spriteBatch.End();

        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
        TIEAdvanced.Draw(Matrix.CreateScale(0.025f), viewMatrix, projectionMatrix);
```

Comment: please add your drawing code into question

Comment: I think I've had similar problems, when I generated lots of particles (sprites) with random Z-layers in my scene. Other sprites started blinking, phasing in and out rapidly. Maybe you're also doing something nasty with Z-layers? Let's see your code!

Comment: Actually I JUST figured it out then - apparently the moment you use the SpriteBatch with .Begin / End it sets the DepthStencilState to None!

Adding 

GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default; 

after the SpriteBatch call fixed it. This would seem like a very common scenario but I had a hard time finding any information on this subject

Comment: also recommended thing is to set blend state to opaque: GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SpriteBatch` will change the following render states. Even if you don't specify any in your `Begin` call - it will use its own defaults:

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.None;
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;
```

When you want to draw 3D models, you will want to set:

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

And, if your 3D models have wrapping UV coordinates:

```
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
```

This information comes from [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112225515/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).

Comment: +1 For XNA 3.x users, [the blog post you're looking for is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2006/11/13/spritebatch-and-renderstates.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunate, but understandable. I ran into this issue since I made an omnipotent RenderLayer class that contained a list of `IDrawable` objects, but since it made no distinction between sprites and 3D (I had simply item.Draw() wedged between begin/end), I was hitting some issues.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, but the code

```
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

resolved the problem.

Comment: Can't make any sense out of this.  Please revise?